# how to get 2nd line of js data in php var OpenWeatherMap

Tags: javascript, php, openweathermap

Here my code

```
$city="Delhi";
$country="IN"; 
$url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=".$city.",".$country."&units=metric&dt=1461412800&cnt=5&lang=en&APPID=xxxxx";
$json=file_get_contents($url);
$data=json_decode($json,true);
```

its returning this ;

```
"weather":[
                 {"id":520,"main":"Rain","description":"light intensity shower rain","icon":"09d"},
                 {"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"},
                 {"id":701,"main":"Mist","description":"mist","icon":"50d"}
              ],
```

How to get 2nd line of data with php ?

Having first line  ; $weather = $data['weather'][0]['description'];

Comment: `$data["weather"][1]["description"]` seems like the next logical step...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the second line, simply grap it this way:

```
$weather = $data['weather'][1]['description'];
```

or if you goal is to list all the result, just use a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).